# How do I troubleshoot/fix search error (when search is successful)?

Tags: search-results, search-builder

I am searching **Contributions** by **Contribution Note** with **Search Builder**.

---

### When no matches are found, it properly says so.

[image]

### However, when the search matches result, there is "DB Error: No such field"

[image]

[image]

## How do I troubleshoot / fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same problem as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3113